# Group By column throwing off query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a query that checks a database to see if a customer has visited multiple times a day.  If they have it counts the number of visits, and then tells me what times they visited.  The problem is it throws "Tickets.lcustomerid" into the group by clause, causing me to miss 5 records (Customers without barcodes).  How can I change the below query to remove "tickets.lcustomerid" from the group by clause... If I remove it I get an error telling me "Tickets.lCustomerID" is not a valid select because it's not part of an aggregate or groupby clause.

The Query that works:

```
SELECT        Customers.sBarcode, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS dtCreatedDate, COUNT(Customers.sBarcode) AS [Number of Scans], 
                         MAX(Customers.sLastName) AS LastName
FROM            Tickets INNER JOIN
                         Customers ON Tickets.lCustomerID = Customers.lCustomerID
WHERE        (Tickets.dtCreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate) AND (Tickets.dblTotal <= 0)
GROUP BY Customers.sBarcode, CAST(FLOOR(CAST(Tickets.dtCreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
HAVING        (COUNT(*) > 1)
ORDER BY dtCreatedDate
```

The Output is:

```
sBarcode   dtcreated Date      Number of Scans  slastname    
1234     1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM         2          Jimbo         
         1/5/2013 12:00:00 AM         3          Jimbo2       
1578     1/6/2013 12:00:00 AM         3          Jimbo3
```

My current Query with the subquery

```
SELECT customers.sbarcode, 
       Max(customers.slastname)                                  AS LastName, 
       Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS 
       dtCreatedDate, 
       Count(customers.sbarcode)                                 AS 
       [Number of Scans], 
       Stuff ((SELECT ', ' 
                      + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dtcreated, 100), 7) AS [text()] 
               FROM   tickets AS sub 
               WHERE  ( lcustomerid = tickets.lcustomerid ) 
                      AND ( dtcreated BETWEEN Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated 
                                                              AS 
                                                              FLOAT)) AS 
                                                   DATETIME 
                                              ) 
                                              AND 
Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated 
AS FLOAT 
)) AS 
DATETIME 
) 
+ '23:59:59' ) 
AND ( dbltotal <= '0' ) 
FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')                      AS [Times Scanned] 
FROM   tickets 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON tickets.lcustomerid = customers.lcustomerid 
WHERE  ( tickets.dtcreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate ) 
       AND ( tickets.dbltotal <= 0 ) 
GROUP  BY customers.sbarcode, 
          Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME), 
          tickets.lcustomerid 
HAVING ( Count(*) > 1 ) 
ORDER  BY dtcreateddate
```

The Current output (notice the record without a barcode is missing) is:

```
sBarcode   dtcreated Date      Number of Scans  slastname    Times Scanned
1234     1/4/2013 12:00:00 AM         2          Jimbo         12:00PM, 1:00PM
1578     1/6/2013 12:00:00 AM         3          Jimbo3        03:05PM, 1:34PM
```

Comment: Oh my, all those `BETWEEN`s and `VARCHAR` without length... <shudder>

Comment: I think it's interesting that you're grouping on customers.sbarcode and getting the count of that column. I'm sure it works since you're not getting a distinct, but in order for this count to be more than one there has to be some other column that is creating the multiple count; using this column for the count would be better from a readability standpoint. Can you explain which table contains records that are not joining to records in the other table? Are there five [tickets] records that don't have a matching [customers] record or vice versa? The solution is probably going to be a left join.

Comment: They are 5 tickets records, and DO have a matching Customers record.  If I run the query, WITHOUT the Subquery, I get the results.  The results that are missing are the 5 without a barcode.  I'll post the query that works, and the output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UPDATE: Based on our "chat" it seems that customerid is not the unique field but barcode is, even though customer id is the primary key.

Therefore, in order to not GROUP BY customer id in the subquery you need to join to a second customers table in there in order to actually join on barcode.

Try this:

```
SELECT customers.sbarcode, 
       Max(customers.slastname)                                  AS LastName, 
       Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME) AS 
       dtCreatedDate, 
       Count(customers.sbarcode)                                 AS 
       [Number of Scans], 
       Stuff ((SELECT ', ' 
                      + RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR, dtcreated, 100), 7) AS [text()] 
               FROM   tickets AS subticket
               inner join
               customers as subcustomers
               on
               subcustomers.lcustomerid = subticket.lcustomerid
               WHERE  ( subcustomers.sbarcode = customers.sbarcode ) 
                      AND ( subticket.dtcreated BETWEEN Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated 
                                                              AS 
                                                              FLOAT)) AS 
                                                   DATETIME 
                                              ) 
                                              AND 
Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated 
AS FLOAT 
)) AS 
DATETIME 
) 
+ '23:59:59' ) 
AND ( dbltotal <= '0' ) 
FOR xml path('')), 1, 1, '')                      AS [Times Scanned] 
FROM   tickets 
       INNER JOIN customers 
               ON tickets.lcustomerid = customers.lcustomerid 
WHERE  ( tickets.dtcreated BETWEEN @startdate AND @enddate ) 
       AND ( tickets.dbltotal <= 0 ) 
GROUP  BY customers.sbarcode, 
          Cast(Floor(Cast(tickets.dtcreated AS FLOAT)) AS DATETIME)
HAVING ( Count(*) > 1 ) 
ORDER  BY dtcreateddate
```

Comment: I don't know that the data or description would help.  The query runs fine if the only grouping is by date and barcode.  Once you group by lcustomerID it drops the tickets without a barcode.  I need to join by lcustomerID in the subquery, otherwise I do not get the "times scanned"

Comment: It would only "drop" the data due to the keys being null, or there not being a record in customers for every ticket and vice versa... I do not know what data is in these tables so can't help with your join. You say it is because they have no barcode, but I do not know which is the barcode, which is the primary key, etc.

Comment: Please see info above, is this specific enough for you?  Or do you need more information?

Comment: So, do you have X customers, then each "scan" as you call it, is a record in the Tickets table?

Comment: Are you trying to have a ROW for each unique customer and date of ticket... so if a customer had three ticket entries, one for today and two for yesterday, they'd have two rows in the output, one for each day, with the aggregate data for each day?

Comment: COrrect.  So you have a Customer (whom is built into the customer table).  When a customer comes in the transaction is put into the (Customer table).  Their barcode is scanned, and the tickets table stores info.  For example time of day the visit took place, amount of the transaction, the lcustomerid etc.  What i'm looking to do... Is see if a customer (from the customer table) was there more than once in a day (this info will be shown in the tickets table) as there will be multiple entries of the lcustomerid and the barcode.

Comment: No, 1 entry for MULTIPLE visits ONLY. I ONLY want to know if a customer came to us more than 1 time on a specific date, in a specific date range.  I do not care about customers who only visited once.

Comment: I want to know how many times that customer was there on a specific day, and what times they were there.  For example If I go in today, at 11am and 1pm I want to know I was there twice.  If I go in tomorrow and was only there at 3pm.  I do not care about that.  If I go in at 12, 1, 3 pm the next day... I want that info.  Again, only the info for MULTIPLE visits on a specific day

Comment: One last question, what data is in dblTotal? Why does it need to be <= 0. I'm wondering if the <= '0' is the problem rather than <= 0.. I can't see too much wrong with your query when breaking it down, other than a few clean ups that I would do to stop the initial confusion.

Comment: the DBLTotal is the amount of money spent.  Basically if the customer has a barcode, and it's scanned it goes to their pre-paid account.  I only want scans that go to a pre-paid account, therefor an amount of 0 or less than 0.  If it's an actual charge on the barcode, I do not care about it.  We are trying to find abuse of pre-paid barcodes.

Comment: I changed '0' to 0, no change in the output

Comment: I've updated my answer with a "rejig" of your query, the main thing being to do the count and having based on the PK of Tickets. Can you give that a go and see what you get?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24138/discussion-between-robin-day-and-shmewnix)

Comment: Same Results.  I also took out the dblTotal completely.  Same results.

Answer (score 1):

I can't directly solve your problem because I don't understand your data model or what you are trying to accomplish with this query. However, I can give you some advice on how to solve the problem yourself.

First do you understand exactly what you are trying to accomplish and how the tables fit together? If so move on to the next step, if not, get this knowledge first, you cannot do complex queries without this understanding.

Next break up what you are trying to accomplish in little steps and make sure you have each covered before moving to the rest. So in your case you seem to be missing some customers. Start with a new query (I'm pretty sure this one has more than one problem). So start with  the join and the where clauses.

I suspect you may need to start with customers and left join to tickets (which would move the where conditions to the left joins as they are on tickets). This will get you all the customers whether they have tickets or not.  If that isn't what you want, then work with the jon and the where clasues (and use select * while you are trying to figure things out) until you are returning the exact set of customer records you need.  The reason why you use select * at this stage is to see what in the data may be causeing the problem you are having. That may tell you how to fix.

Usually I start with a the join and then add in the where clasues one at a time until I know I am getting the right inital set of records. If you have multiple joins, do them one at time to know when you suddenly start have more or less records than you would expect.

Then go into the more complex parts. Add each in one at a time and check the results. If you suddenly go from 10 records to 5 or 15, then you have probably hit a problem. When you work one step at a time and run into a problem, you know exactly what caused the problem making it much easier to find and fix.

Group BY is important to understand thoroughly. You must have every non-aggregated field in the group by or it will not work. Think of this as law like the law of gravity. It is not something you can change. However it can be worked around through the use of derived tables or CTEs. Please read up on those a bit if you don't know what they are, they are very useful techniques when you get into complex stuff and you shoud understand them thoroughly. I suspect you will need to use the derived table approach here to group on only the things you need and then join that derived table to the rest of teh query to get the ontehr fields. I'll show a simple example:

```
select 
      t1.table1id
    , t1.field1
    , t1.field2
    , a.field3
    , a.MostRecentDate
From table1 t1
JOIN
    (select t1.table1id, t2.field3, max (datefield) as MostRecentDate 
    from table1 t1
    JOin Table2 t2 on t1.table1id = t2.table1id
    Where t2.field4 = 'test'
    group by t1.table1id,t2.field3) a
    ON a.table1id = t1.table1id
```

Hope this approach helps you solve this problem.